# PyTorch backward() on a tensor element affected by nan in other elements

Tags: python, pytorch, nan, autograd

Consider the following two examples:

```
x = torch.tensor(1., requires_grad=True)
y = torch.tensor(0., requires_grad=True)
z = torch.full((2, ), float("nan"))
z0 = x * y / y
z1 = x + y
print(z0, z1) # tensor(nan, grad_fn=<DivBackward0>) tensor(1., grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
z1.backward()
print(x.grad) # tensor(1.)


x = torch.tensor(1., requires_grad=True)
y = torch.tensor(0., requires_grad=True)
z = torch.full((2, ), float("nan"))
z[0] = x * y / y
z[1] = x + y
print(z) # tensor([nan, 1.], grad_fn=<CopySlices>)
z[1].backward()
print(x.grad) # tensor(nan)
```

In example 1, `z0` does not affect `z1`, and the `backward()` of `z1` executes as expected and `x.grad` is not nan. However, in example 2, the `backward()` of `z[1]` seems to be affected by `z[0]`, and `x.grad` is `nan`.

How do I prevent this (example 1 is desired behaviour)? Specifically I need to retain the `nan` in `z[0]` so adding epsilon to division does not help.

Comment: You want to know why 2nd example is giving "nan" and 1st example is not giving "nan", right ?

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer Yes and I wish to know how to get non-nan behavior for loss (final node in the computational graph) stored in tensors, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When [indexing](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/gradient-value-is-nan/91663/4) the tensor in the assignment, PyTorch accesses all elements of the tensor (it uses binary multiplicative masking under the hood to maintain differentiability) and this is where it is picking up the `nan` of the other element (since `0*nan -> nan`).

We can see this in the computational graph:

| `torchviz.make_dot(z1, params={'x':x,'y':y})` | `torchviz.make_dot(z[1], params={'x':x,'y':y})` |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

If you wish to avoid this behaviour, either [mask the `nan`'s](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/nans-in-input-data-breaking-gradients/58504/2), or do as you have done in the first example - separate these into two different objects.

Comment: Thank you! Based on my understanding I need to prevent assigning the problemetic value to `z[0]` in the first place, is that correct? Masking `z` in any way after assigning values does not seem to help.

Comment: @jerry yes, avoiding assigning `nan`s to any element in the tensor will resolve this.

Comment: Could one approach be assigning a custom value - something which you are sure your model would not output and then creating a mask etc.? then the gradient at that value would not be nan and getting multiplied by 0 would still serve our purpose?